# PHP: Mail sending takes too long

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a simple contact form on a webpage but as I hit send it takes about 30 seconds to process the `mailer.php` file and load the thank you page.

I've read every other page and they all suggest adding the IP `127.0.0.1` to `hosts` file which in my case is already present. I've tried php's default `mail` function and `phpmailer` library as well, both take the same amount off time.

Here are a few last lines of my `maillog` file in `/var/log/maillog`

```
Jul 14 03:11:27 vps11868 spamd[24360]: zoom: able to use 998/999 'body_0' compiled rules (99.899%)
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::INET [#177_]:783 (running version 3.4.1)
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server pid: 24360
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 3444
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 3445
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: child states: BI
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[3444]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:63698 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[3444]: spamd: setuid to cpaneleximscanner succeeded
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[3444]: generic: trusted_networks doesn't contain internal_networks entry '0/0'
Jul 14 03:11:42 vps11868 spamd[3444]: spamd: checking message <269ea2061a4f1afc85252deb13b3371c@bwdmedia.net> for cpaneleximscanner:32011
Jul 14 03:11:46 vps11868 spamd[3444]: spamd: clean message (3.1/5.0) for cpaneleximscanner:32011 in 4.3 seconds, 2022 bytes.
Jul 14 03:11:46 vps11868 spamd[3444]: spamd: result: . 3 - HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,NO_RELAYS,TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_ONLY,URIBL_BLOCKED scan$
Jul 14 03:11:46 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: child states: II
Jul 14 03:13:48 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killing failed child 3445 fd=7 at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/522/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/SpamdFor$
Jul 14 03:13:48 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killed child 3445
Jul 14 03:13:48 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killing failed child 3444 fd=6 at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/522/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/SpamdFor$
Jul 14 03:13:48 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killed child 3444
Jul 14 03:13:49 vps11868 spamc[3457]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
Jul 14 03:13:51 vps11868 spamd[24360]: zoom: able to use 998/999 'body_0' compiled rules (99.899%)
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::INET [#177_]:783 (running version 3.4.1)
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server pid: 24360
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 3460
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 3461
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: child states: BI
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[3460]: spamd: connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:64104 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 14 03:14:06 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: child states: II
Jul 14 03:14:07 vps11868 dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<__cpanel__service__auth__imap__prg7lq3thmic88s2cgdxk5s_mgkrpmerbicb_xiadgkfvc...>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0$
Jul 14 03:14:07 vps11868 dovecot: imap(__cpanel__service__auth__imap__prg7lq3thmic88s2cgdxk5s_mgkrpmerbicb_xiadgkfvclvhrvasdqvqwi_pzr9): Logged out in=11, out=434, byt$
Jul 14 03:16:08 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killing failed child 3460 fd=6 at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/522/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/SpamdFor$
Jul 14 03:16:08 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killed child 3460
Jul 14 03:16:08 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killing failed child 3461 fd=7 at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/522/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/SpamdFor$
Jul 14 03:16:08 vps11868 spamd[24360]: prefork: killed child 3461
Jul 14 03:16:08 vps11868 spamd[24360]: spamd: handled cleanup of child pid [3461] due to SIGCHLD: interrupted, signal 2 (0002)
Jul 14 03:21:09 vps11868 spamc[3530]: connect to spamd on ::1 failed, retrying (#1 of 3): Connection refused
Jul 14 03:21:12 vps11868 spamd[24360]: zoom: able to use 998/999 'body_0' compiled rules (99.899%)
```

Any troubleshooting tips to help diagnose the situation?

Comment: Maybe it's a hosting issue. Is the email received after 30 seconds as you said?

Comment: Yeah. I get to the thank you page and receive the email right after that

Answer (score 0):

Phpmailer use SMTP of gmail. So it takes time, You can use mail script which you can find on google

Comment: He already said used the mail() function and had the same result.